# Receiving "Method 'Range' of object_Global' failed" when trying to insert formula into entire column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am receiving the following error message when trying to insert the below formula into the AS column.

*Run-time error '1004':
Method' "Range" of object'_Global' failed*

Can someone please take a gander at my code and call out any mistakes? I'm driving myself crazy here.

```
 Sub Zero_Dollar_Opps()

 Dim LastRow As Long

 LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

'name last column $0 Opps
 Range("AS1").Value = "$0 Opps"

'insert formula for $0 Opps
 Range("AS2:AS" & LastRow).Formula = "=IF(AND(AP2=0,(OR(AL2=""1 - 
 Qualifying"", AL2=""2 - Validating"", AL2=""3 - Proposing"", AL2=""4 - 
 Negotiating""))),1,0)"

End Sub
```

Thank you Stackoverflow community!

Comment: is your formula really split up into multiple lines like above?

Comment: No, all in one line. Sorry, should have clarified

Comment: When it stops what is the value of LastRow?  I get no error with your code.

Comment: Ran it today with identical code...no issues...weird

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
Sub Zero_Dollar_Opps()

 Dim LastRow As Long

 LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

'name last column $0 Opps
 Range("AS1").Value = "$0 Opps"

'insert formula for $0 Opps
 Range("AS2:AS" & LastRow).Formula = "=IF(AND(AP2=0,(OR(AL2=""1 - Qualifying"", AL2=""2 - Validating"", AL2=""3 - Proposing"", AL2=""4 -Negotiating""))),1,0)"

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Gary's Student, could you please point out the change? It looks identical to the original code

Comment: @Kcyr  I removed the double quote before `Qualifying`

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Tried this morning w/ identical code and received no error messages. I knew there was a reason why I hated VBA..